# Crash of simple fortran program using system()

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
program x
   character(len=1024) :: foo 
   integer:: ret 

   foo = 'ls'
   call system(foo, ret)
end program
```

This program crashes with SIGSEGV on ifort.

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000100000F0B  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000100000EAA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000100000E8B  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000100000E0C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000100000DA4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

gdb:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100000f0a in allocCstr ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100000f0a in allocCstr ()
#1  0x0000000100000eaa in system_ ()
#2  0x0000000100000e0c in main ()
```

ifort --version

```
ifort (IFORT) 11.1 20100806
Copyright (C) 1985-2010 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error that you're seeing if I copy your code (Linux, ifort 11.0 20090131).  However, a check of the Intel fortran compiler manual suggests that it's a function rather than a subroutine.  If I modify the code to:

```
program x
    character(len=1024) :: foo
    integer             :: ret

    foo = 'ls'
    ret = system(foo)
end program x
```

Then it works successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works on my machine (ifort, xp sp3)

```
  CHARACTER(LEN=1024) :: FOO
  INTEGER :: RET

  FOO = 'dir'
  CALL SYSTEM(FOO, RET)
  READ(*,*)

  END
```

Also with

```
  RET = SYSTEM(FOO)
```

Also works on the same ifort you're using, xp sp2.